# How do I authorize with Google without staying signed in to Google in my browser

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, gmail, authorization

I'm making a desktop app in Python that sends mail from Gmail. The problem is that after receiving consent (OAuth 2) through the browser, the user for whom the software receives the consent, continues to be logged in to the browser in Gmail. Is there a way to go through the authorization process without staying logged in to Gmail in your browser?

Comment: you can try to use some Web widget in your desktop app to display web page directly in your program. And then you don't have to use browser.

Comment: And when Web widget will display token then you can get it directly from this widget without copy/paste.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and be clear what it is you are trying to achieve as well as include a [example]

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is Oauth2.  Oauth2 gives users the ability to grant applications like yours consent to access their private data.  Private data is data that is owned by someone.   My gmail data is mine your application can not use it unless I grant you access.

> Is there a way to go through the authorization process without staying logged in to Gmail in your browser?

Lets clear up some confusion in this statement you mention authorization which is correct a user is authorizing your application to access their data.   Yet you also mention logged in which has nothing to do with authorization.  Logging in a user is authentication and is not part of Oauth2.   It is part of something else called openid connect.

As for how to request authorization of a user without using the browser.  Once the user has consented to your application accessing my data once then your application should have what its called a refresh token, this refresh token can be used at a latter time for your application to request a new access token. Granting you access to may data without using the browser to access my data again. So you could store this refresh token in the backend some where and use that to continue to access the users data without needing to use the browser again.

## storing user credentials in an installed application

It is hard to know exactly what you are doing since you did not include any code in your question, and your question is a little unclear.

In the following example please note how the users credentials are stored in gmail.dat using this code in an installed application will cause it to load the refresh token the next time the user runs the app meaning that the consent screen should not be shown, as the credentials are already stored for that user.

```
def initialize_gmail():
  """Initializes the gmail service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized gmail service object.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage('gmail.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build('gmail ', 'v1', http=http)

  return service
```